# Linear regression with pandas time series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe object which contains 1 seconds intervals of the EUR_USD currency pair. But in theory it could be any interval and in this case it could look like this:

```
2015-11-10 01:00:00+01:00    1.07616
2015-11-10 01:01:00+01:00    1.07605
2015-11-10 01:02:00+01:00    1.07590
2015-11-10 01:03:00+01:00    1.07592
2015-11-10 01:04:00+01:00    1.07583
```

I'd like to use linear regression to draw a trend line from the data in dataframe, but I'm not sure what the best way are to do that with time series, and even such a small interval of time series.

So far I've messed around by replacing the time by (and this is just to show where I'd like to go with it) a list ranging from 0 to the time series list length.

```
x = list(range(0, len(df.index.tolist()), 1))
y = df["closeAsk"].tolist()
```

Using numpy to do the math magic

```
fit = np.polyfit(x,y,1)
fit_fn = np.poly1d(fit)
```

Lastly I draw the function along with the df["closeAsk"] to make sense of the trend.

```
plt.plot(x,df["closeAsk"], '-')
plt.plot(x,y, 'yo', x, fit_fn(x), '--k')
plt.show()
```

However now the x-axis is just meaningless numbers, instead I'd like for them to show the time series.

Comment: Why don't you just substitute `df["time_series_data"]` in for `x` when plotting?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment:

Say you have some **evenly spaced** time series data, `time`, and some correlated data, `data`, as you've laid out in your question.

```
time = pd.date_range('9:00', '10:00', freq='1s')
data = np.cumsum(np.random.randn(time.size))

df = pd.DataFrame({'time' : time,
                   'data' : data})
```

As you've shown, you can do a linear fit of the data with `np.polyfit` and create the trend line with `np.poly1d`.

```
x = np.arange(time.size) # = array([0, 1, 2, ..., 3598, 3599, 3600])
fit = np.polyfit(x, df['data'], 1)
fit_fn = np.poly1d(fit)
```

Then plot the data and the fit with `df['time']` as the x-axis.

```
plt.plot(df['time'], fit_fn(x), 'k-')
plt.plot(df['time'], df['data'], 'go', ms=2)
```

[image]

Comment: What if you do not have evenly spaced time series data?

Answer (score 0):

May be you wil be happy with seaborn?
Please try 
[seaborn.regplot](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.regplot.html)

[image: Plot the relationship between two variables in a DataFrame]

Comment: seaborn regplot doesn't work with time series, which is essential to this question.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a numpy linspace for the x-values in the same length as your datapoint like so:

```
y = df["closeAsk"].dropna() # or.fillna(method='bfill')
x = np.linspace(1, len(y), num=len(y))

import seaborn as sb

sb.regplot(x, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on the accepted answer, here's a neat way to plot both trend and data from any pd.Series, including time series:

```
trend(df['data']).plot()
```

Where `trend.plot` is defined as follows (generalized from the accepted answer):

```
def trend(s):
    x = np.arange(len(s))
    z = np.polyfit(x, s, 1)
    p = np.poly1d(z)
    t = pd.Series(p(x), index=s.index)
    return t

trend.plot = lambda s: [s.plot(), trend(s).plot()]
```

If you need just the trend data (not the plot):

```
trendline = trend(df['data'])
```