# Times Series Using Linear Regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, linear-regression

I have some time series data for prices that I'm trying to perform linear regression on. However, I feel that what I'm doing is incorrect and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

My data looks like this:

```
date             Close
2017-05-10      0.12512
2017-05-11      0.12353
2017-05-12     -0.35235
.
.
.
2019-01-10      0.87890
```

`Close` refers to the closing price of each day and is scaled to be within (-1, 1).

I've attempted to use linear regression from the `sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression` library. When I initially ran it to fit the data, `date` is a string type and so the program alerted me that it cannot work with string data. So I simply dropped the date column and just worked with the `Close` values in the training and test set.

My intuition tells me that this is the wrong approach. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37337836/linear-regression-with-pandas-time-series) there is something called Polyfit in NumPy. Is it impossible to use the standard Scikit-Learn Linear Regression with the data that I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LinearRegression is not the solution for TimeSerie

In the context of Statistics, linear regression is solved by maximizing the likelihood that the error of a model linear in basis is the mean of a Normal Distribution. During maximization we assume the observations are independently and identically distributed, clearly not a reasonable assumption for times series data.

For TimeSerie problem, there are many solutions depend on what is your problem.
http://www.statsoft.com/textbook/time-series-analysis

if you want to predict the next value, i suggest `RNN` basically